# codeigniter registration form not displaying the errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

```css
<?php
Class Register extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();       
         $this->load->helper(array("form","url"));
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
         $this->load->library('session');
         $this->load->library('email');

         $this->load->view("register_view");
         $this->load->model("Register_model");
         $this->load->database();

    }

    public function index(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Name', 'required|min_length["3"]',array("required"=>"username is required","min_length"=>"min of 3char"));    
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile','Mobile','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pwd','Password','required|min_length["6"]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpwd','Confirm Password','required|matches["pwd"]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('terms','Terms & Conditions','required');


        if($this->form_validation->run()==true){

            $username=$this->input->post("uname");
            $email=$this->input->post("email");
            $password=$this->input->post("pwd");
            $mobile=$this->input->post("mobile");
            $state=$this->input->post("state");
            $gender=$this->input->post("gender");
            $terms=$this->input->post("terms");
          //  $uid=$this->input->post("");

            $status=$this->register_model->insertData($name,$email,$password,$mobile,$state,$gender,$terms);

                if($status==true){

                    $config=array('protocol'=>'smtp',
                                'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                                'smtp_timeout'=>10,
                                'smtp_port'=>465,
                                'smtp_user'=>'r********@gmail.com',
                                'smtp_pass'=>'********',
                                'charset'=>'utf-8',
                                'mailtype'=>'html',
                                'newbie'=>'\r\n',

                          );

                   $to=$email;
                   $subject="Acc activation -$uname";
                   $message="Hi. your acc created. pkease clicl here to activate<br/>

    <a href='base_url()'register/activate/uniid >Activate</a> ";

             $this->email->intialize($config);
             $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
             $this->email->set_crif("\r\n");
             $this->email->from('r**********@gmail.com','company');
             $this->email->to($to);
             $this->email->subject($subject);
             $this->email->message($message);

             if($this->email->send()){
                $this->session->set_tempdata("success","account created please activate",2);
                redirect(current_url());
             }

             else{
                print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
             }

            }
            else{
                print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
        }                
    }
 }
 ?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

   <h1>Register form</h1>


    <?php if($this->session->tempdata("error")){
       echo"<p>". $this->session->tempdata("error"). "</p>";
    }

    if($this->session->tempdata("success")){
        echo"<p>".$this->session->tempdata("success"). "</p>";
    }
?>
```

```
<table>

   <tr>
      <td>Name </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo set_value('uname'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Email </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Password </td>
       <td><input type="password" name="pwd" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Confirm Password </td>
       <td><input type="password" name="cpwd" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Mobile </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo set_value('mobile'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Gender </td>
       <td>
          <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if(set_value('gender')=='male') echo 'checked';   ?> /> Male
          </label>

          <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if(set_value('gender')=='female') echo 'checked';   ?> /> Female
          </label>

       </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Select state </td>
      <td>
         <select name="state">
             <option value="">---Select State----</option>
             <option <?php if(set_value("state")=="Delhi") echo 'selected'; ?> value="delhi" >Delhi</option>
         </select>
      </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="1" <?php if(set_value("terms")=="1") echo "checked";  ?> />
        Please accept terms and condiotions
        </label>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
</tr>
```

In this code I saved controller as Register.php and view as register_view.php loaded libraries of form validation, session, email and helpers like form, url which are required. I also loaded these in autoload.php file. But its not showing the form validation errors, set values. its just submitting and showing the same page. what are changes needs to be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how this question is related to laravel?

Comment: some time it would be email setup error.

Comment: Remove Email then try

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like,

```
 if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {

                $this->load->view("add");
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Yes. insted i wrote

Comment: if($this->form_validation->run()==true){

            $username=$this->input->post("uname");

Comment: you must add $this->load->view("your view"); and return false;

Answer (score 0):

Will you please add load view end of the  `if($this->form_validation->run()==true){}else{}` condition.

```
if($this->form_validation->run()==true){

}
 $this->load->view("register_view");
```

Please try this one.

Comment: i changed it in else condition. but no use

Comment: may be you have to write "$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());" in else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
  //Do your code 
}else{
   echo validation_errors();
   die;
}

$this->load->view('layout/admin');
```